# How to add exception handling to SqlDataSource.UpdateCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sqldatasource

We have a radgrid that is automatically updated with the `SqlDataSource.UpdateCommand`. So when we edit some column(s) and click on "Update" the table is updated correctly with `UpdateCommand` in the markup.

It looks something like this:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" AllowAutomaticUpdates="true" >
<MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="City" CommandItemDisplay="Top"  AllowAutomaticUpdates="true">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" UniqueName="EditCommandColumn">
            </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="City" HeaderText="City" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="City"
                UniqueName="City" >
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Prefix" HeaderText="Prefix" UniqueName="Prefix">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="sector" HeaderText="sector" UniqueName="sector">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RF-PRConnectionString %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT STATEMENT" runat="server"
UpdateCommand= "UPDATE STATEMENT">
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="sector" Type="String" />
</UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

But let's say that the update generates an exception in the table (ie. tried to update an Int with varchar, violates some key, etc). Is there any way I can add a `Try...Catch` to `SqlDataSource.UpdateCommand`? I wouldn't know how to since there's no code behind that does the update, everything is done through `SqlDataSource`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simple solution: I need to handle the `OnRowUpdated` event.

```
protected void GridView_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception != null)
    {
        //show error message
        e.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```